# Does Elasticsearch Sink Connector support upsert mode on primary key like the JDBC sink connector does?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

I'm moving data from Mongodb -> Elasticsearch using kafka connect.
At the moment the updated records are inserted as new documents in the Elasticsearch indices. However I want to update the exisiting records based on a ID (Similar to write.mode=upsert in JDBC Sink Connector). Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but to do upserts, note the [updated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561257/6952495): `write.method=upsert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting up `key.ignore=false` then transform the event key from `{id: 1234} to 1234` using the `ExtractField` SMT

```
    key.ignore=false
    transforms=ExtractField
    transforms.ExtractField.field=id
    transforms.ExtractField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
```